# Needed: ROS node manager

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, rosnode

We've moved to ROS/ROS2 from [LCM](https://lcm-proj.github.io/lcm/) for a few systems in the lab.  We used LCM a lot and liked the [libbot/procman](https://github.com/ashuang/procman) sheriff interface.  It was great for launching/stopping programs, seeing their printouts, and keeping track of things in a simple interface.  (See example screenshot)  I can not find an equivalent for ROS/ROS2.  I don't understand why.  We've got 10-15 nodes to keep track of and launch files, but it is mess of terminals and jumbled prints.  My experience watching others use ROS is similar.  Within 5 minutes of running a system they've got 8 terminals open to track what is happening.

What am I missing?

[image: procman]

Comment: What are 8 terminals being used for?

Comment: We've got different launch files set up for different parts of the vehicle, that are run in terminals.  If you have too many nodes in a launch file the print statements are impossible to sort out.  The vehicle may have 15 processes running and the control computer may have another 5.   The libbot sheriff was a easy way to manage all of this.  I can't believe there is no equivalent for ROS.

Comment: Does https://github.com/xqms/rosmon work for you?  I looked at it a little a few months ago but ran into some issues running it on Ubuntu 22.04 and didn't pursue it further.  Feel free to answer your own question with details of how it compares to procman.

Comment: Can you add links to libbot/procman in your question?  I see a few possible github pages but am not sure

Comment: I think we get lobbot from here   https://github.com/ashuang/procman.  It is getting old and unsupported, which is one reason we moved to ROS.  LCM has been rekindled a bit more recently, https://github.com/lcm-proj/lcm.  I did just find this, https://github.com/ori-drs/procman_ros, which looks like a ros enabled version of procman.

Comment: It looks like rosmon is not going to support ROS2, https://github.com/xqms/rosmon/issues/143